# Drupal 6: creating different profiles to list at custom page adding page and selecting as many as i want

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, profile, cck

I'm a newbie drupal...

I'm working on my first Drupal project. I need to make an events page for some conferences. I create event content type, and creating fields like date-place-title-etc with CCK. There are also speakers, can be up to 20. each speaker has photo-namesurname-position. same speaker can be added to more than 1 event. So it is silly to create 60 fields (photo-name-position) for 20 speakers at event adding page. and expecting admin to fill all for an event adding action.

there must be a way to create speakers additionally, and listing them at event adding page with checkboxes. and admin just select the speakers from the list, can be 1 or 20 speaker.

how can create such thing? in what type should I create these speakers, so i can list them in event adding page for admin to select as many as he wants.

Appreciate helps so much!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a 'speaker' content type, containing the photo, name and potentially other speaker specific information. With this, you can create one node per speaker.

To reference speakers from other nodes (e.g. events), you can add a CCK nodereference field to the event type, allowing you to select speaker nodes as referenced by the event.

You can restrict the nodes selectable for the nodereference field based on a view, e.g. on one filtering by content type 'speakers'.